# loop in optim in R: May you help me to adjust my loop code

Tags: r, optimization, loops

May you help me correct my loop function.

I want optim to estimates al_j; au_j; sigma_j;  b_j by looking at 0 to 20, 21 to 40, 41 to 60 data points.

The final result should have 4 columns of each of the estimates AND 4 rows of each of 0 to 20, 21 to 40, 41 to 60.

MY code is:

```
n=20
runs=4
out=matrix(0,nrow=runs)

llik = function(x)
{
    al_j=x[1]; au_j=x[2]; sigma_j=x[3];  b_j=x[4]
    sum(na.rm=T,
        ifelse(a$R_j< 0, -log(1/(2*pi*(sigma_j^2)))-
                        (1/(2*(sigma_j^2))*(a$R_j+al_j-b_j*a$R_m))^2,
        ifelse(a$R_j>0 , -log(1/(2*pi*(sigma_j^2)))-
                        (1/(2*(sigma_j^2))*(a$R_j+au_j-b_j*a$R_m))^2,
                        -log(pnorm(au_j,mean=b_j*a$R_m,sd=sqrt(sigma_j^2))-
                        pnorm(au_j,mean=b_j*a$R_m,sd=sqrt(sigma_j^2)))))

    )

}

start.par = c(0, 0, 0.01, 1)
out1 = optim(llik, par=start.par, method="Nelder-Mead")


for (i in 1: runs)
{
index_start=20*(i-1)+1
index_end= 20*i
out[i]=out1[index_start:index_end]
}
out
```

My data:

```
R_j            R_m
-0.0625       0.002320654
0             -0.004642807
0.033333333   0.005936332
0.032258065   0.001060848
0             0.007114057
0.015625      0.005581558
0             0.002974794
0.015384615   0.004215271
0.060606061   0.005073116
0.028571429  -0.006001279
0            -0.002789594
0.013888889   0.00770633
0             0.000371663
0.02739726   -0.004224228
-0.04         0.008362539
0            -0.010951605
0             0.004682924
0.013888889   0.011839993
-0.01369863   0.004210383
-0.027777778  -0.04658949
0             0.00987272
-0.057142857 -0.062203157
-0.03030303  -0.119177639
0.09375       0.077054642
0            -0.022763619
-0.057142857  0.050408775
0             0.024706076
-0.03030303   0.004043701
0.0625        0.004951088
0            -0.005968731
0            -0.038292548
0             0.013381097
0.014705882   0.006424728
-0.014492754  -0.020115626
0             -0.004837891
-0.029411765  -0.022054654
0.03030303    0.008936428
0.044117647   8.16925E-05
0             -0.004827246
-0.042253521  0.004653096
-0.014705882 -0.004222151
0.029850746   0.000107267
-0.028985507 -0.001783206
0.029850746  -0.006372981
0.014492754   0.005492374
-0.028571429 -0.009005846
0             0.001031683
0.044117647   0.002800551
```

Comment: Can you generalize this so that it may pertain to the larger R community?

Comment: I have created a code that works that estimates variables using optim in R. I want the code to perform a loop(as I have attempted at the bottom) but I am missing somehing?

Comment: Follow on from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560072/why-the-parameter-i-am-trying-to-estimate-is-not-found

Answer (score 0):

When I try and run your code I get the error message "`a` not found" when `llik` is called.  You should refactor your code so that all the variables that `llik` needs are either passed into it or created within the function.

The line `out[i]=out1[index_start:index_end]` also looks dubious, since you are assigning a range of values to a single location.

Comment: a is where the data is. the code is as follows>a=read.table("E:/data.txt",header=T) >attach(a) in a is where R_j and R_m are. Thanks Edward